# How to combine multiple boolean comparisons into one

Tags: java, boolean, stack

I'm trying to find a short way to write this (in Java) (note in this case top is a Node in a linkedlist)

```
if(top.data.equals("A") || top.data.equals("B") || top.data.equals("C") ||....)
    postfix.push(pop());
```

My goal is something like

```
if(top.data.equals("A", "B", "C", "D", ....)
```

Is there a way to do this in Java? (I don't even know what to call it to do further research in the API and elsewhere).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if (Arrays.asList("A","B","C").contains(top.data))`

Comment: It isn't having any compilation errors with that, but it did have me add a "throws Exception" declaration on the method. What sort of error could that run across? (Or is it having me throw that since it is using Arrays)

Comment: Oh, I just read the comment under Josh's answer.  I guess if `top.data` isn't a `String`, you could either call `toString()` (like in Josh's answer), or include actual objects in the call to `asList`.

Comment: Your way still works, in this program it is guaranteed to contains a String/Character of some sort, but I wasn't sure if the "indexOf" would work since it wasn't declared as a String.

Comment: Oh, are you saying you've declared it as an `Object` even though you're putting `String` values into it?  If that's the case, then just do a cast.

Answer (score 0):

```
if("ABC".indexOf(top.data.toString()) > -1){ .... }
```

Or

```
if("ABC".contains(top.data.toString())) { .... }
```

Comment: Would this work since data is just a generic Object?  (I declared it as Object data; )

Comment: Now it would. Was unaware that `data` was an `Object`.